# proc hpgenselect in SAS with categorical predictors

Tags: sas, lasso-regression

I am running a lasso regression with a binary endpoint using the neuralgia data set analysed here with logistic https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_logistic_examples02.htm&locale=en
I run this code

```
proc hpgenselect data=Neuralgia;
  class Treatment Sex;
      model Pain= Treatment Sex Treatment*Sex Age Duration / binary;
SELECTION METHOD=lasso DETAILS=all;     
ods output ParameterEstimates=peLASSO;      /*Outputs parameter estimates dataset*/   
output out=predLASSO pred=Lpred pzero=Lzero;
run;
```

However - in contrast to proc logistic - for categorical predictors such as binary sex I get non-zero estimates for both levels (male and female) rather than a single non-zero estimates giving the effect of one sex relative to the other (reference) level. This is in contrast to ordinary (non-LASSO) logistic regression. Why is this ? Is this a general feature of lasso or do I need to recode categorical predictors somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

The default parameterization or creating dummy variables for categorical variables is GLM while the most common method taught is Referential coding. What you're referring to from the logistic regression is referential coding.

The default in PROC LOGISTIC and HPGENSELECT for the [CLASS statement](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=stathpug&docsetTarget=stathpug_introcom_stat_sect003.htm&locale=en) is both GLM, but since you didn't show the code I don't know what options were specified in the LOGISTIC procedure.

Either way, change the parameterization to REF and you'll get referential coding.

```
class Treatment Sex / param=REF;
```

PS. Check the odds ratio explicitly if you'd like to make sure it's the same. Those shouldn't change.

Answer (score 0):

wow many thanks Reeza that does work - the proc logistic code is in the link I posted and strangely that doesn't have the / param=REF  option but neverthless .. thanks again :)